# get upload progress in yii & bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm using yii-bootstrap to display the progress of a file that is being uploaded in an iframe:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbProgress', array(
    'type'=>'info',
    'percent'=>40,
    'striped'=>false,
    'animated'=>false,
)); ?>
```

Is there a native way to find out the progress of the file that is being uploaded in Yii? I don't want to use a Yii extension as I have everything written and uploading correctly already, I just need to display the progress. So really I just need the percentage value.

Comment: Standart upload do not can be `progressed`. Upload's progress able only via something like  http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

Comment: thanks, but implementing a flash uploader seems a bit backwards these days...

Answer (score 0):

As Sergey said, it's not possible in pure php to display the progress of an upload. But you could use Javascript to do it.

Here's an example in php and javascript that you could adapt to your need:
[A Simple PHP Upload Progress Bar](http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/)

Comment: It is possible to do it in PHP with APC or progressupload PHP extensions and a meta-refresh on an iFrame

Comment: @keeg: looks like you found your answer, then?

Comment: @DCoder I'm hoping for a native Yii solution, all the extensions out there come with the uploader and the progressbar, I want something that just returns the progress

Comment: @keeg: seems to me that writing your own solution would be faster, given the small amount of code necessary.

Comment: @DCoder: Oh I so don't want to hear that! Why can't there be `CUploadedFile::getUploadProgress()`  ?

Comment: @keeg: because you haven't written it yet!